# Need help making a drawing using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

I need to make a code in python that draws the output below using recursion and a function named drawpoly. drawpoly() will take 6 arguments which include a turtle, the length of a side, the number of sides, red, green & blue. While the number of sides is > 2, drawpoly() will recursively call itself decrementing the number of sides by 1 each call. Red will increment by 10, green by 25 & blue by 35 each call. I need to set fillcolor and begin and end fill. I will also need will need to set the screen colormode to be able to use integers to make your colors.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

her's the code I have so far It doesn't print out anything but its a rough outline of what I need to use in the program

```
wn = trtl.Screen()
def drawpoly(trtl, num_sides, side_length,color):
    numOfSides=8
    num_sides=8
    side_length=100
    color="blue"
    while (numOfSides >2):
        trtl.drawpoly(trtl,num_sides,side_length,color)
        numOfSides -=1

def main():
    return drawpoly

main()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65dS4.png
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm just wondering how to get my code to print the correct output using recursion

Comment: Your program seems to do no drawing at all. Perhaps you should start with a smaller program which just draws a small number of lines.

Comment: Presumably right now it doesn't print anything because you're never actually calling it. Your main function should be `drawpoly()` not `return drawpoly`. Once you've fixed that what output do you get and how does it differ from what you expect?